# What email service would work best in this scenario?

Tags: email, nginx, email-server, drupal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Recommended SMTP Relay Service](https://serverfault.com/questions/289063/recommended-smtp-relay-service)

I am using a VPS server at Linode to host a few Drupal websites.

For web I am using Nginx, and all email is hosted with Google Apps.

I need to be able to allow Drupal to send out emails, but is installing postfix the best method, or can I get away with something smaller since all I need on the server is outgoing email?

Thank you

Comment: @mailq: no. Out of the box Drupal/PHP on Linux requires a command line mail client - a relay service is not the same thing.

Comment: @symcbean Yes, sendmail has a (the!) command line mail client and can be configured as a SMTP relay.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with [sSMTP](http://packages.qa.debian.org/s/ssmtp.html); "extremely simple MTA to get mail off the system to a mail hub".  Surely Google Apps has an SMTP gateway.

Comment: Sorry for the slow response, but I will check this solution out today.

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment elsewhere, by default, [Drupal provides a wrapper](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--mail.inc/function/drupal_mail_system/7) around php's mail() function. On non-MSWindows boxes the PHP mail() system works by invoking a program on the local system to send the email. In the case of MSWindows, you simply tell PHP where there is an SMTP server to use (but it does not provide for sSMTP/startTLS/authentication).

So an obvious solution is to install a simple MTA which provides a CLI client. [nullmailer](http://untroubled.org/nullmailer/) is a fairly obvious choice.

Alternatively you can configure Drupal to use an SMTP handler instead of 'mail()'. Drupal [now offer such a module](http://drupal.org/project/smtp) based on phpmailer.

But if your connection to the SMTP relay is not VERY reliable, or if you'll never need to perform anything more complex to your emails (e.g. tying to SPF, adding signatures, metering) then a proper queuing MTA would be the way to go.